# How do I complete the sentence "If it's no trouble, ____"?

Tags: sentence-construction, politeness

I'm trying to learn the sentence structure and I had a few thoughts about the possible structural continuations of the sentence. I was wondering if you could introduce any new possible continuations to the sentence to me.

"If it's no trouble, **I'd like (you) to stay** with him this afternoon"

"If it's no trouble, **I want/ask/wish (you) to stay** with him this afternoon"

"If it's no trouble, **I'd appreciate you staying** with him this afternoon"

"If it's no trouble, **I'd appreciate your help/assistance/helping** hand with this"

(I'm always looking to improve on my English; so, I'd greatly appreciate it if you would point out any grammatical mistakes I've made in describing my question)

Answer (score 2):

"If it's no trouble" is a *precondition* to what comes next, therefore it only really works with a *request*, not an order. It doesn't make logical sense to tell someone they *must* do something - but only if it is no trouble to them.

Of your examples, the only one I would question is "I *want* you to..." ("ask" and "wish" don't sound quite right in this context). This is because it sounds like a demand. The other examples are perfectly idiomatic and are polite requests.

Answer (score 0):

"If it is no trouble (for you)" is a polite prerequest that can be followed by a "would", a "could", also a "might/may I ask you to" and a "please".

- If it's no trouble for you, please close the window.
- If it's no trouble for you, would be so kind as to give me a glass of water.
- If it's no trouble for you, could you make me tea.
- If it's no trouble for you, may I ask you to turn the volume down a little.

At the end of each sentence you can add "please" to be even more polite.